# Can't Remove CiviCrm Membership Type From Being Visible Publicly

Tags: civimember

I tried disabling, making visibility admin only, and then finally deleting a specific CiviCrm Membership Type, but still can't remove it from being seen publicly on Contribution Page. Anyone know what is causing this and how to fix it?

FYI I was able to edit other membership types and those changes became visible.

Using Wordpress 4.6.1
Using CiviCrm 4.7.7

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I just saved the changes in the contribution page and that somehow fixed it. Not clear how the price changes updated (without saving) but not the actual membership type, but that's okay.